# How to create .aip file (Adobe Illustrator Plugin file)?

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

How to create .aip file (Adobe Illustrator Plugin file)?
I know how to create .zxp file with ZXPSignCmd.exe.
But how to create .aip file?

I need something which will not be possible to open, so code inside will be protected, is .aip file good for that?

Comment: There are .jsxbin files in the wild. I don't know much about it. As far as I can tell they are plain JSX scrips saved as non-editable binary files. Probably this is the thing you want: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/how-to-compile-jsxbin-file/m-p/8625386

Answer (score 0):

To create an Adobe Illustrator Plugin file with the extension .aip, you need to use the Adobe Illustrator SDK. The SDK provides a set of tools and resources that allow you to develop and package your plugin for distribution.

Here are the steps to create an .aip file:

1. Download and install the Adobe Illustrator SDK from the Adobe Developer Connection website.
2. Create a new project in Visual Studio using the Illustrator SDK template.
3. Write your plugin code in C++ or JavaScript.
4. Build your project to generate the .aip file.

Please note that the `.aip` file format is specific to Adobe Illustrator and is not intended to be opened or edited by users. The file is designed to be installed as a plugin in Adobe Illustrator and should be distributed as such.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. 

I made a plugin written in JavaScript that works nice.
So that's it, I would say completed step 3 of the ones you mentioned.

But I don't know where to start with these other steps.
Can you please send me some useful links beginner friendly if possible or link for some tutorial?

Comment: Also just to mention I created this extension using Adobe-CEP is this possible to integrate with steps that you mentioned above?

Comment: _I made a plugin written in JavaScript that works nice_ I'm afraid you've made a script (JSX), not a plugin. They're not the same thing. I'm surprised that (if) a plugin can be written in Javascript. I though it's C++ only. But I'm not an expert in plugins, I can be wrong in this area.

Comment: I made extension (I run though Window>Extension;). It has html/JavaScript part as well as ExtendScript part. Only I am not sure if that Adobe-CEP approach is possible to use to create .aip file.